# History goBack not working at function component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't make a button that send de user to the previous page and I don´t know why, I've already done it at a class component and works, but know I'm trying to do it at a function component and it crashes

See the code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/recursableComponents/Header";
import { BASE_URL } from "../consts";

    function Collections(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const [collections, setCollection] = useState([]);
  const [choosedCollection, setChoosedCollection] = useState("");

  const getCollections = () => {
    const user = new User();
    const id_marca_estilo = user.user.id_marca_estilo;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header
        title="Coleções"
        rightIcon={null}
        leftIcon={
          <IconButton
            aria-label="upload picture"
            component="span"
            className={classes.whiteButton}
            onClick={() => props.history.goBack()}
          >
            <ArrowBack></ArrowBack>
          </IconButton>
        }
      />
```

Comment: Can you please share the error message or the crashing details? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are on v5+ of react-router-dom

You have to use the `useHistory` hook as follows

`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';`

Then in your functional component

`const history = useHistory();`

Finally
`onClick={() => history.goBack()}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-router you can have access to history using a hook:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

// (...)

function Collections(props) {
  const history = useHistory(); // <=============


  const { classes } = props;
  const [collections, setCollection] = useState([]);
  const [choosedCollection, setChoosedCollection] = useState("");

  const getCollections = () => {
    const user = new User();
    const id_marca_estilo = user.user.id_marca_estilo;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header
        title="Coleções"
        rightIcon={null}
        leftIcon={
          <IconButton
            aria-label="upload picture"
            component="span"
            className={classes.whiteButton}
            onClick={() => history.goBack()}
          >
            <ArrowBack></ArrowBack>
          </IconButton>
        }
      />
```

Check docs for more details:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {withRouter} from "react-router";

export default function RoutingGoBackExample() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about/insideabout">Inside About</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/about">
                        <About/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/about/insideabout">
                        <InsideAbout/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

const About = withRouter(({history, ...props}) => (
    <div>
        <h1>
            About
            <hr/>
            <button onClick={() => {
                // history.push('/')
                history.goBack(-1);
            }}>go back
            </button>
        </h1>
    </div>
));

const InsideAbout = withRouter(({history, ...props}) => (
    <h1 {...props}>
        Inside About
        <hr/>

        <button onClick={() => {
            history.goBack();
        }}>go back
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => {
            history.go(-2);
        }}>go home
        </button>
    </h1>
));
```

[More Detail](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)